# Google Compute Engine - Persistent Disk

Tags: google-compute-engine

I'm trying to find the 500gb persistent disk attached to my google compute instance. When I use the VM or SSH and do 'df -h' it lists about 10gb. there is a 10gb partition that references my persistent disk. Can anyone tell me how I mount the other 490gb? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to repartition your root persistent disk following the steps 4-14 listed in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/disks#repartitionrootpd).

Also you might like to know that some days ago, other person and me faced an issue repartitioning the disk, so if the official documentation doesn't work for you, take a look at [this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gce-discussion/WZHXBc4zWbU/PzNeb22Uf6gJ).

I hope this can help you.

Comment: The Google documentation has been updated, the issue was related to the start partition, since it might be different that the one in the doc.